# Cómo encontrar los archivos de secuencia de comandos de Google Apps Script en Google Drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive

La búsqueda avanzada de Google Drive incluye diversos tipos de archivos pero no incluye las secuencias de comandos

[image: Lista de tipos de archivos en Búsqueda Avanzada - Google Drive]

¿Cómo puedo encontrar todos los archivos de secuencia de comandos de Google Apps Script en Google Drive?

Por archivos de secuencia de comando me refiero a los proyectos independientes, los cuales son llamados en la documentación como [standalone script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/standalone)

> A standalone script is any script that is not bound to a [Google
>   Sheets, Docs, or Forms file](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound) or [Google Sites](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web). These scripts appear
>   among your files in Google Drive.

Nota: En este caso se está preguntando por Google Drive como una herramienta para programadores para buscar específicamente archivos de secuencia de comandos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De acuerdo a [Buscar archivos en Google Drive - Ayuda de Google Drive](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2375114?hl=es) se puede usar el operador `type:` seguido de parámetro `script` de la siguiente forma:

[image: type:script]